# LVM2: lvcreate -L - What does 's', 'S' suffix stand for?

Tags: lvm

`man lvcreate` - Am I blind or there is no description for "sS" ? (I can't find on redhat manual pages as well)

```
-L, --size LogicalVolumeSize[bBsSkKmMgGtTpPeE]
              Gives  the  size  to allocate for the new logical volume.
              A size suffix of K for kilobytes, M for megabytes, G for
              gigabytes, T for terabytes, P for
              petabytes or E for exabytes is optional.
              Default unit is megabytes.
```

Comment: You may want to submit a request to the maintainers to add that documentation to the lvcreate man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sectors.

See this patch:
https://www.redhat.com/archives/lvm-devel/2009-July/msg00018.html

Comment: I love it when developers add features and don't bother to document them.

Comment: The `pvs`, `vgs` and `lvs` man pages have all the units, but some other man pages haven't been updated.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the name of the sS but it takes 2048 of s to make 1m so kilobytes are double the size of s because it only takes 1024k to equal 1m.