# Move a logical volume from one volume group to another

Tags: linux, lvm

Is it possible to move a logical volume from one volume group to another in whole?

It is possible to create a (more or less) matching lv and copy the data over, but is there any way to do this with LVM tools alone?

If not, is there a theoretical reason or a technical limitation (extent sizes)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precise answer to this question is: "No, it is not possible to (logically) *move* a Logical Volume (LV) from one Volume Group (VG1) to another (VG2). The data must be physically copied."

Reason: Logical Volume data is physically stored on block devices (disks, partitions) assigned to a specific Volume Group. *Moving* Logical Volume from VG1 consisting of `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` to VG2 consisting of `/dev/sdc` would require to *move* data from `/dev/sda` and/or `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/sdc` which is a *physical copy* operation between at least two block devices (or partitions).

P.S. 
If all the LV data was stored on the Physical Volume, which could be completely excluded from the VG1, then this Physical Volume could be assigned to VG2. But then it would be moving a Physical Volume from one Volume Group to another, not a move of a Logical Volume.

Comment: Great answer; if you have any reference you used to, please add them; they would make your answer greater!

Answer (score 21):

A volume group consists of whole physical volumes. A physical volume consists of many extents (an extent is typically 4MB); each extent may belong to a different logical volume. To transfer a logical volume to a different group, you cannot simply transfer extents, because that might split the physical volume between the source VG and the target VG.

What you can do is transfer one or more PVs from the source VG to the target VG, with the [`vgsplit`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/vgsplit) command. You can specify which PVs you want to transfer, or which LV (but only one at a time). If you specify an LV, it and the other LVs in the source VG must be on separate PVs. The destination VG will be created if no VG exists with the specified name.

```
vgsplit -n source_group/volume_to_copy source_group target_group
vgsplit source_group target_group /dev/sdy99 /dev/sdz99
```

You may need to use [`pvmove`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pvmove) first to arrange for the logical volumes you want to move to be on separate PVs.

If you meant to retain the physical boundaries of the VG and move the data, there's no built-in tool, but you could [make a mirror then remove the original](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34785/backup-of-lvm2-logical-volume/34800#34800).

Comment: Looks like the target_group can be a pre-existing one?

Comment: why the two vgsplit commands? What's the difference between the two invocations?

Comment: @confusedCoder The first one transfers the physical volume(s) containing the specified logical volume. The second one transfers the specified physical volume(s).

Answer (score 17):

As of the LVM in Debian stretch (9.0), namely 2.02.168-2, it's
possible to do a copy of a logical volume across volume groups using a combination of `vgmerge`, `lvconvert`, and `vgsplit`. Since a move is a combination of a copy and a delete, this will also work for a move.

Alternatively, you can use `pvmove` to move the physical extents instead. To quote [U&L: Purpose of Physical Extents](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664525/4671):

> A single physical extent is the smallest unit of disk space that can be individually managed by LVM.

A complete self-contained example session using loop devices and
`lvconvert` follows.

Summary: we create volume group `vg1` with logical volume `lv1`, and `vg2` with `lv2`, and make a copy of `lv1` in `vg2`.

Create files.

```bash
truncate pv1 --size 100MB
truncate pv2 --size 100MB
```

Set up loop devices on files.

```bash
losetup /dev/loop1 pv1
losetup /dev/loop2 pv2
```

Create physical volumes on loop devices (initialize loop devices for use by LVM).

```bash
pvcreate /dev/loop1 /dev/loop2
```

Create volume groups vg1 and vg2 on /dev/loop1 and /dev/loop2
respectively.

```bash
vgcreate vg1 /dev/loop1
vgcreate vg2 /dev/loop2
```

Create logical volumes lv1 and lv2 on vg1 and vg2 respectively.

```bash
lvcreate -L 10M -n lv1 vg1
lvcreate -L 10M -n lv2 vg2
```

Create ext4 filesystems on lv1 and lv2.

```bash
mkfs.ext4 -j /dev/vg1/lv1
mkfs.ext4 -j /dev/vg2/lv2
```

Optionally, write something on lv1 so you can later check the copy was correctly created. Make vg1 inactive.

```bash
vgchange -a n vg1
```

Run merge command in test mode. This merges vg1 into vg2.

```bash
# vgmerge -A y -l -t -v <<destination-vg>> <<source-vg>>
vgmerge -A y -l -t -v vg2 vg1
```

And then for real.

```bash
vgmerge -A y -l -v vg2 vg1
```

Then create a RAID 1 mirror pair from `lv1` using `lvconvert`. The
`dest-pv` argument tells `lvconvert` to make the mirror copy
on `/dev/loop2`.

```bash
# lvconvert --type raid1 --mirrors 1 <<source-lv>> <<dest-pv>>
lvconvert --type raid1 --mirrors 1 /dev/vg2/lv1 /dev/loop2
```

Then split the mirror. The new LV is now `lv1_copy`.

```bash
# lvconvert --splitmirrors 1 --name <<source-lv-copy>> <<source-lv>>
lvconvert --splitmirrors 1 --name lv1_copy /dev/vg2/lv1
```

Make `vg2/lv1` inactive.

```bash
lvchange -a n /dev/vg2/lv1
```

Then (testing mode)

```bash
# vgsplit -t -v <<source-vg>> <<destination-vg>> <<moved-to-pv>>
vgsplit -t -v /dev/vg2 /dev/vg1 /dev/loop1
```

For real

```bash
vgsplit -v /dev/vg2 /dev/vg1 /dev/loop1
```

Resulting output:

```
lvs
[...]
lv1        vg1       -wi-a-----  12.00m
lv1_copy   vg2       -wi-a-----  12.00m
lv2        vg2       -wi-a-----  12.00m
```

NOTES:

1. Most of these commands will need to be run as root. The `#` in front of some of the commands indicates that it is a comment. It does not represent the root prompt.
2. If there is any duplication of the names of the logical volumes in the two volume groups, `vgmerge` will refuse to proceed.
3. On merge, logical volumes in `vg1` must be inactive. And on split, logical volumes in `vg2` belonging to `vg1` must be inactive. In our case, this is `lv1`.

Comment: Nice runthrough. Ended up using to move LVs to different set of disks with new UUIDs, where I normally DD and deal with duplicates.

Answer (score 8):

I will offer my own:

```
umount /somedir/

lvdisplay /dev/vgsource/lv0 --units b

lvcreate -L 12345b -n lv0 vgtarget

dd if=/dev/vgsource/lv0 of=/dev/vgtarget/lv0 bs=1024K conv=noerror,sync status=progress

mount /dev/vgtarget/lv0 /somedir/
```

if everything is good, remove the source

```
lvremove vgsource/lv0
```

Comment: This is pretty much the opposite of the question. The point is to move the volume instead of copying the data to a new one.

Comment: I think this is actually a good answer. There is no 'move' in this context. Just a copy and delete. This answer describe pretty much exactly what will happen if you 'move' the lv.

The difference here is that this is more transparent to the user and thus safer.

Comment: I considered the complicated solution, and just keep coming back to the simplest method. Make a new lv, and make a bit for bit copy. lvm is not zfs, I like it that way, and I prefer the dumb solution.

Comment: This is essentially a poor man's version of `pvmove` without any of the safety offered by that command. Being "more transparent" doesn't make it safer in the slightest. The `dd` part cannot be done online (you have to stop using the source lv for the entire duration of the copy), a single typo in the `dd` command can destroy data. `pvmove` will never destroy any of your data, no matter how hard you screw up or how badly stuff fails. Worst case, you'll be left with your original LV and an incomplete mirror.

Comment: I didn't do `dd` between two SSDs because I'm not sure how it handles `trim` operations

Comment: The only problem with pvmove is the start, pv. When you want to move a logical volume, you do not want to mess with physical volumes or even mess up a volume group with random temporary  guest PVs. ZFS handles it more transparent by allowing you to export/import a volume through send-receive.

Comment: @TooTea keep in mind that pvmove had serious bugs for quite a few years in the far past and would definitely lose data (at least from a lvm pov), i.e. if it OOM'ed.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have a volume named `s0`

`$ pvs -o+pv_used`

```
PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   Used
/dev/sda2  cl lvm2 a--  <118.24g      0  <118.24g
/dev/sdb   s0 lvm2 a--  <223.57g      0  <223.57g
/dev/sdc1  s0 lvm2 a--  <465.76g      0  <465.76g
/dev/sdd1     lvm2 ---   931.51g 931.51g       0
```

I want to move `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc1` to a new psychical disk `/dev/sdd1`

#### Create a physical volume on sdd1

`$ pvcreate /dev/sdd1`

#### You can now extend your Volume Group `s0` with the new disk

`$ vgextend s0 /dev/sdd1`

#### You can now start moving data

`$ pvmove /dev/sdb /dev/sdd1`

Wait to finish

```
/dev/sdb: Moved: 10.0%
...

/dev/sdb: Moved: 50.0%
...

/dev/sdb: Moved: 100.0%
```

#### Check

`$ pvs -o+pv_used`

```
PV         VG Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   Used    
/dev/sda2  cl lvm2 a--  <118.24g      0  <118.24g
/dev/sdb      lvm2 ---   223.57g 223.57g       0 
/dev/sdc1  s0 lvm2 a--  <465.76g      0  <465.76g
/dev/sdd1  s0 lvm2 a--  <931.51g 707.94g <223.57g
```

#### Now you can remove `/dev/sdb` from the `s0` group

`$ vgreduce s0 /dev/sdb`

Follow the same steps for `/dev/sdc1`

Comment: This also is not an answer to the question as the LV is still in the same volume group. Only PVs have been changed.

Answer (score -1):

When I want to copy `lv1` from `vg1` to `vg2` I create `/dev/vg2/lv1` (same size as
`/dev/vg1/lv1`) and use:

```shell
blocksync.py -f /dev/vg1/lv1 localhost /dev/vg2/lv1
```

It also works across servers.

When you use it for making regular copies, it will skip sending identical blocks. For move just drop `/dev/vg1/lv1` afterwards.

Comment: is `blocksync.py` a standard tool ? If not, where to find it ? how to install it ?

Comment: `blocksync.py` is a GPLed script available at GitHub

Comment: It is OK to use non standard tools, just mention it in the post.