# Move root filesystem on a logical volume to a different disk

Tags: linux, grub2, lvm

I'm trying to move my root LV to a new VG on my brand new SSD and it's driving me crazy. I think I pulled it off with rsync, but now grub is refusing to register the new boot option off of /dev/vg_ssd/lv_root. Why doesn't linux have cplv or lvmove like AIX?

I want to use vg_ssd/root to mount to / instead of vg_dopey/lv00. /boot is separate. Grub2/FC17.
Linux dopey 3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Oct 17 02:43:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lvdisplay

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_ssd/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vg_ssd
  LV UUID                oDms4t-cKve-Eg27-jdcW-H3Wu-kvhs-qHhJQm
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time dopey, 2012-10-22 20:25:31 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                32.00 GiB
  Current LE             8191
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_dopey/lv01
  LV Name                lv01
  VG Name                vg_dopey
  LV UUID                2tSy4L-kPnC-8rSE-jXX8-Dad4-9F4v-TPVmQz
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time dopey, 2012-10-01 22:50:49 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                468.69 GiB
  Current LE             14998
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg_dopey/lv00
  LV Name                lv00
  VG Name                vg_dopey
  LV UUID                SYe9Ze-XFUb-kIcu-UxEO-dhMd-ubaf-oAphsk
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time dopey, 2012-10-01 22:50:53 -0400
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                19.53 GiB
  Current LE             625
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

/etc/fstab, both on new and old root lvs

```
#/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 /                       ext4    defaults        1 1
UUID=587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
/dev/vg_dopey/lv01      /home       ext4    defaults    1 2
UUID=8dec0c61-6593-4e1d-a7b1-86de1816a601 /opt/media              ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=910763ef-317b-4c48-b92f-8f24a729ffb8 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
#/dev/mapper/vg_ssd-root
UUID=f7ada493-298d-4c09-8260-a8988ede1cfe / ext4 discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

/boot/grub2/grub.cfg

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub2-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
set default="${saved_entry}"

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod part_msdos
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
set root='lvm/vg_dopey-lv00'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvm/vg_dopey-lv00'  67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
set timeout=5
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Fedora' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 ro rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=True rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_dopey/lv00 rhgb quiet 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /initramfs-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Fedora' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
    menuentry 'Fedora, with Linux 3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64-advanced-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 ro rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=True rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_dopey/lv00 rhgb quiet 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64.img
    }
    menuentry 'Fedora, with Linux 3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 (recovery mode)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64-recovery-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 ro single rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=True rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_dopey/lv00 rhgb quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.6.2-4.fc17.x86_64.img
    }
    menuentry 'Fedora, with Linux 3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64-advanced-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 ro rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=True rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_dopey/lv00 rhgb quiet 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64.img
    }
    menuentry 'Fedora, with Linux 3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64 (recovery mode)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64-recovery-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 ro single rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=True rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_dopey/lv00 rhgb quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.6.1-1.fc17.x86_64.img
    }
    menuentry 'Fedora, with Linux 3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64-advanced-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 ro rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=True rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_dopey/lv00 rhgb quiet 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64.img
    }
    menuentry 'Fedora, with Linux 3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64 (recovery mode)' --class fedora --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64-recovery-67deba56-4839-41c3-8c51-46185c8efd0e' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos6 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos6 --hint='hd0,msdos6'  587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 587081f1-e607-43bd-85f5-7632d833726e
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64 ...'
        linux   /vmlinuz-3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 ro single rd.md=0 rd.dm=0  KEYTABLE=us SYSFONT=True rd.luks=0 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 rd.lvm.lv=vg_dopey/lv00 rhgb quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /initramfs-3.5.6-1.fc17.x86_64.img
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_ppc_terminfo ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Microsoft Windows XP Professional (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-AA0C2EE80C2EAF6F' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1 --hint='hd0,msdos1'  AA0C2EE80C2EAF6F
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root AA0C2EE80C2EAF6F
    fi
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

mount

```
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,seclabel,size=2013244k,nr_inodes=503311,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,seclabel,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,seclabel,mode=755)
/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv00 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,seclabel,discard,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
selinuxfs on /sys/fs/selinux type selinuxfs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,seclabel,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime,seclabel)
tmpfs on /media type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,seclabel,mode=755)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
/dev/sdc1 on /opt/media type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/sda6 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/vg_dopey-lv01 on /home type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /run/user/me/gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
```

Comment: What you trying to archive? Duplicate existing LVs to the SSD?

Comment: Exactly. I managed to do it by following [link]http://www.void.gr/kargig/blog/2012/01/11/linux-ssd-partition-alignment-tips/ but I can't seem to get grub to go for the root fs on the ssd instead of the old one on the hdd. /boot is a regular old logical partition.

Comment: Using grub1.9X?

Comment: grub2. ran grub2-install /dev/sda. My boot-flagged partition is on sda (the hdd). ssd is /dev/sdb.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374665/4671

Answer (score 2):

`pvmove` will move your LVs within a VG from the existing PVs to another PV.

That may solve your problem...

Comment: I thought about that, but I want to remake the filesystem from scratch to match the block size. `mkfs.ext4 -O extent -b 4096 -E stride=128,stripe-width=128 /dev/mapper/ssd-debian`

Comment: If you insist on modifying block size, you might be able to do the right combination of `lvcreate` and `lvrename` calls so that you create the LV on the SSD and then rename the LV's such that te new one has the same name as the old.

Answer (score 0):

Your fstab sounds broken, just modify `/etc/fstab`, and change the line that mounts your root to the new one, probably the UUID=XXX,

To find all uuids, run `blkid` as root.

If your grub.cfg is out of date, use `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to re-generate the  grub.cfg

**EDIT**

Note that when grub scans for the root device, it takes current mounted one as root. You will need to modify the grub.cfg manually and boot from SSD, afterwards, run the `grub-mkconfig` again

Comment: My fstab is fine, I think. See above.
The issue is that grub.cfg is still pointing to the old root fs and causing all kinds of havoc. and grub2-install isn't picking up the new root fs on the ssd.
The current setup causes errors, the old root fs mounts ro, stopping x/gdm, I remount to rw and x/gdm starts.

Comment: I appreciate the help you're giving me. =]

Comment: Right, still broken. grub2-mkconfig output is still pointing at lv00 (old hdd root fs), not lvroot (new ssd)

Comment: @lvm_headaches show the output of `mount` ? Also check the update

Comment: Updated grub.cfg with UUID and /dev/mapper for new root, rebooted. Failed to dracut. Posted mount above.