# Setting GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true in /etc/default/grub not working as expected

Tags: linux, grub2

I'm using Debian stretch (9.0), the current stable. My arch is AMD64. My root and boot partitions are LVM volume groups on top of an MD RAID 1 device.

According to my understanding of the documentation, uncommenting

```
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true
```

in `/etc/default/grub` should stop GRUB2 from using UUIDs in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. However, it continues to use UUIDs even after I have made that change.

I'm not sure if this is somehow user error on my part, but the instructions seem simple enough.

A couple of additional comments.

1. There is also a file `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`, which has
   identical contents (same md5sum) to `/etc/default/grub`. I'm not
   sure what the point of that file is.
2. I would expect `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` to include a check for
   `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID`, but I don't see one, though that script
   does include `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID`. Can someone explain to me
   where this script is checking `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID`?

I can post more details if it would help, of course.

Background: I was motivated to change this because the UUID of my root VG changed, and my machine refused to boot, saying that the UUID didn't exist. Which was correct. It didn't any longer. See [Unable to determine sync status errror when trying split LVM2 RAID 1 mirror](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/375051/4671) for how that happened.

Debian bug report: [grub-common: Setting GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true in /etc/default/grub does not work as expected](https://bugs.debian.org/867206).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61586/discussion-on-question-by-faheem-mitha-setting-grub-disable-linux-uuidtrue-in).

Answer (score 1):

(This answer tries to explain what is happening and offers a (possible) patch.)

It seems the offending code is in `grub-mkconfig_lib` lines 169-182 in current Debian 9.

The point of the bug is that the setup and boot insists on setting up and using the UUID for one part of the boot process despite not being told to by the sysadmin/configuration.

Possibly failing to load grub.cfg in consequence. e.g. it is always doing `grub-probe --target=fs_uuid /` in `grub-mkconfig_lib` ; in our case should be `grub-probe --target=device /` or to be code specific, it should use `$fs_hint`, and not redo again `grub_probe` with `fs_uuid`

I have done a patch to disable the generation of UUID when `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID` is configured as true for Debian 9. It works here. Please test it.

I confirm again the offending file is: `/usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib`

I wrote a patch that if `GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID` is set to `true`, it does not include the `search` directive trying to select an UUID based root. The sysadmin should then understand the consequences of selecting this option when inserting new disks.

The patch for  `/usr/share/grub/grub-mkconfig_lib` was done with:

```
diff -u grub-mkconfig_lib.old grub-mkconfig_lib > grub-mkconfig_lib.patch
```

and is here:  https://jpst.it/10_iY

or you can get it here:

https://github.com/ruyrybeyro/grub-mkconfig_lib.patch

and to apply it:

```
cd /usr/share/grub
patch -p0 < grub-mkconfig_lib.patch
```

Basically, starting on line 169, I added the new if, and proper indentation, to disable the root partition search for UUID that supersedes the choice by device *if a partition with a valid UUID is found*:

```
  if [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID}" != "xtrue" ] ; then
```

> ```
>    if fs_uuid="`"${grub_probe}" --device $@ --target=fs_uuid 2> /dev/null`" ; then
>       hints="`"${grub_probe}" --device $@ --target=hints_string 2> /dev/null`" || hints=
>       echo "if [ x\$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then"
>       echo "  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ${hints} ${fs_uuid}"
>       echo "else"
>       echo "  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ${fs_uuid}"
>       echo "fi"
>     fi
> ```

```
  fi
```

I tested it, regenerating the grub config, changing the UUID, and it booted without a hitch, contrary to the former situation, where we would be dropped into grub.

PS: This seems not to be restricted to Debian. After I pin pointed it to `grub-mkconfig_lib` I found a related thread about [fedora](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/29209/how-do-i-set-grub2-to-use-labels-versus-uuid-in-search/)

Comment: Nice work, Rui. I'll try to test this patch today. But could you regenerate with `diff -u`, please? That's more standard. I don't know why it's not the default. Or add it to your previous paste, if you prefer.

Comment: diff done with -u

Comment: Thanks very much, Rui. I'll test it and get back to you. And any other Debian users out there, please also test.

Comment: And any non-Debian users, please check if this bug applies to you too.

Comment: Just a side comment - a good way to paste/post a patch is by using gist-`paste`, from the `gist` package. It makes a git repository for the file.

Comment: I thought about upload to my github, thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm not clear how long that gist repos will stick around for, but it's a reasonable short term solution, and probably better than the average paste site. See also https://help.github.com/articles/creating-gists/#creating-an-anonymous-gist. Note also that `gist-paste` will authenticate to your existing Github account if you want it to - see `man gist-paste`.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Did it work?

Comment: I'm looking at it now. I'd replace your pastebin by a gist link. I think it will be easier for people to work with, as they can just clone the git repos. I'm having to cut and paste from the pastebin web page, which is inelegant, and may introduce errors. And do make sure to use `diff -u`.

Comment: You should also include your patch in the question, though make it clear that people should use the gist to obtain the patch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61707/discussion-between-faheem-mitha-and-rui-f-ribeiro).