# Filesystems Size Single Letter Abbreviation

Tags: linux, lvm, units

In many file system related man page, the units are represented by single letters [bBsSkKmMgGtTpPeE]. What do the upper case and lower case mean? I.e. megabyte, megabit, mebiyte, mebibit, which one is which?

Comment: possible duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34776/98965

Answer (score 6):

Unix tools are not consistent, you need to check the man page of each one.

LVM utilities *are* consistent, and some (but not all) of the man pages have the details. For example, from [lvs(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvs.8.html):

> All sizes are output in these units: (h)uman-readable, (b)ytes, (s)ectors, (k)ilobytes, (m)egabytes, (g)igabytes, (t)erabytes, (p)etabytes, (e)xabytes.  Capitalise to use multiples of 1000 (S.I.) instead of 1024.

I.e. `b` or `B` is bytes, `s` or `S` is sectors (of 512 bytes), `K` is 1000 bytes (SI kilobyte), `k` is 1024 bytes (kibibyte), `M` is 1000000 bytes (SI megabyte), `M` is 1048576 bytes (mebibyte), etc.

More generally, `b` is never bits in the context of file or disk sizes; it's usually bytes but might occasionally be blocks (and the size of blocks depends on the tool as well). The prefixes k/m/g/t/p/e can mean powers of 1000 or powers of 1024 depending on the tool and sometimes on capitalization. S for sectors as in LVM is unusual. Another common unit (not used by LVM) is `c` for bytes; this comes from **c**haracter, from back in the days before multibyte characters were common.

Answer (score 1):

Some LVM commands, such as `lvcreate`, make no difference between units given as lower-case letters and units given as upper-case letters. `b` or `B` means bytes, `s` or `S` means sectors of 512 bytes,  `k` or `K` means binary kilobytes (2^10 = 1024 bytes), `m` or `M` means binary megabytes (2^20 = 1 048 576 bytes), `g` or `G` means binary gigabytes (2^30 = 1 073 741 824 bytes), `t` or `T` means binary terabytes (2^40 = 1 099 511 627 776 bytes), `p` or `P` means binary petabytes and `e` or `E` means binary exabytes. Documented in `man lvcreate` under the option `-L`. Other LVM commands, such as `lvs`, take lower-case units to mean powers of 2 and upper-case units to mean powers of 10.

Other commands have different conventions. For example `dd` wants `K`, `M`, `G` for binary units and `kB` (not `KB`), `MB`, `GB` for decimal units; `du` and `df` use `K`, `M`, `G` for binary units and `KB` (not `kB`), `MB`, `GB` for decimal units; read the manual pages for the commands that you want to use.

No filesystem-related command uses sizes in bits. They are always in bytes.

Comment: No, LVM *does* make a distinction between uppercase and lowercase for prefixes: uppercase means powers of 1000.

Comment: @Gilles: We are _both_ rigtht (and both wrong, at the same time). `lvcreate` makes no distinction. `lvs` makes a distinction. Try it and see.

Answer (score -1):

Small b letter signifies bit, capital letter B signifies byte

```
MB/mB = megabyte 
Mb/mb = megabit
```

The mathematical explanation is simple:

```
MiB = Mebibyte = 1024 KiB
KiB = Kibibyte = 1024 Bytes
MB = Megabyte = 1,000 KB
KB = Kilobyte = 1,000 Bytes
```

Comment: Only capital letter M should be used for mega, a small letter m means milli, i.e. one thousandth. Kilo should be abbreviated k, not K. K is used for Kelvin, which is a unit for temperature. Often you see K for 1024 and k for 1000, but kiB is a better abbreviation for 2 to the power of 10 bytes.

Comment: This is not true in the context of disk or file sizes: they are never expressed in bits, `b` could mean bytes or blocks (bytes in the case of LVM) but not bits.

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the man page of `lvcreate`

```
-L|--size LogicalVolumeSize[b|B|s|S|k|K|m|M|g|G|t|T|p|P|e|E]
Gives the size to allocate for the new logical volume. A size suffix of 
b or B for bytes,
s or S for sectors  as  512  bytes,  
k or K for kilobytes, 
m or M for megabytes, 
g or G for gigabytes, 
t or T for terabytes, 
p or P for petabytes or E for exabytes is optional.
Default unit is megabytes.
```

Capitalized to used only for present it as multiples of 1000 instead of 1024.
Can also specify custom units e.g. --units 3M

Comment: This is true but so incomplete as to be useless.